# Taking the inner text from almost same structure of dom

Tags: javascript

I use this dom command to take an inner html:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#back-item div#back-offer div div header h5 span strong a')[0].innerHTML
```

and example of html after div

```
<div id="item-5959">
<div id="item-5959-view">
<header>
<h5 class="item-logo">
<h4>
<h5>
<span class="select">
<strong>
<a href="http://www.example2.com">Printer</a>
</strong>
</span>
</h5>
```

from which I take the innerHTML Printer.

Using another dom

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#background-experience-container div#background-experience div div header h5 a')[0].innerHTML
```

and example of html

```
<div id="item-18995"">
<div id="item-18995-view">
<header>
<h4>
<h5>
<a href="http//www.example.com">Photo</a>
</h5>
</header>
```

and I take the innerHTML Photo from this.

The difference between the 2 dom commands is the "span strong"

However using the second command there are more results in the dom with 
this structure. How can I make the two dom commands into one?

Comment: Note that `document.querySelectorAll(...)[0]` is more efficiently written `document.querySelector(...)`.

Comment: *"However using the second command there are more results in the dom which this structure."* What does that mean? Do you mean that you have more than one result for the selector?

Comment: Could you please paste the whole html? The ones you showed are not formatted, and contain numerous errors

Comment: You might just add a custom class or attribute to your `a` elements, and simply query those

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean using this `document.querySelectorAll('div#background-experience-container div#background-experience div div header h5 a')` I expect to see 2 but I receive 6. I could expect to see the 2 so that is the reason I want like to combine them using the same command because they are in the second category but which different html structure the data I like to collect

Comment: @hege_hegedus I can add in `a` a name = 'item'`

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to find an element that has possible wrappers around it :/ It's possible in jQuery though with find().

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom classes and a selector:

```
<a href="http://www.example2.com" class="interesting-class-1">Printer</a>
```

The selector looks like:

```
var html = document.querySelector('.interesting-class-1').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't change the structure of html the only addition in the a is a dir=class. What worked for me is `document.querySelectorAll('div#back-item div#back-offer div[id*=item] div[id*=item] header h5')` `document.querySelectorAll('div#back-item div#back-offer div[id*=item] div[id*=item] header h5').getElementsByTagName('a[dir=*check]')` Could there is any way to take the a element even it is in span strong or not?

Comment: @Berbery Why don't you just use `document.querySelectorAll('a[dir*=check]')`?